# Moveit-catkin build

Tags: ros, moveit, catkin, build, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why does source installation of moveit package needs to be built with catkin build command instead of catkin_make? What is the advantage of doing so.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249898/moveit-catkin-build/) by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 243 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It does not *need* to.

`catkin_make` works perfectly fine.
Dave Coleman wrote the current build instructions and he's a proponent of the catkin tools over `catkin_make`.
It handles some things more "user-friendly" than `catkin_make`, among other things it automatically deals with pure-cmake projects inside the workspace (`catkin_make_isolated` is required for that). I suppose this is especially important for Dave as he often builds OMPL within the same workspace as far as I know.

Personally, I believe building up *more* software on top of cmake just moves us back in the direction of rosbuild and that's not were I want to go.. But I do see the "user-friendliness argument".

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2016-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2016-12-12**:
Its ability to build non-catkin CMake projects is a huge selling point for me, yes. And the ability to delete and rebuild specific packages without having to rebuild the entire workspace is huge. Perhaps we should note on the source install page that catkin_make is fine as well - could you do that?